# selecting the account after calculating the sum over its user names

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I would need to know how to select the account after calculating the sum of their exposures. 
My dataset looks like:

```
expos   account users 
12      1241    2141
341     1241    5123
41      412     21
12      413     43
```

My expected output would be

```
sum(expos)   account 
353     1241    (sum over users on time=12)
41      412     
12      413
```

To try to achieve this, I am currently using this code:

```
sel expos
, sum (expos) over (partition by account)
, account
, users
from table_1 tab1
inner join table_2 tab2
on tab1.users=tab2.users
where time=12
```

But the output is giving me not only the sum but also the other single values.

How can I get output shown above?

update: expos comes from table 1 and it was calculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want to drop `users` and `expos` from the `group by`:

```
select sum(expos) over (partition by account), account
from table_1 tab1 inner join
     table_2 tab2
     on tab1.users = tab2.users
where time = 12
group by account
```

Comment: I would need to keep expos as it was calculated. so I think I should use a where statement to select it from tab 1. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need simple aggregation instead of *Windowed Aggregates*

```
select sum (expos) 
  , account
from table_1 tab1
inner join table_2 tab2
on tab1.users=tab2.users
where time=12
group by account
```

Comment: I would need to keep expos as it was calculated. so I think I should use a where statement to select it from tab 1. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't understand what you want, this returns exactly the expected output